# ES6 / BABEL let scope

Tags: cordova, scope, ecmascript-6, babeljs, let

I have a function which I have implemented in ES6. All is working fine, except accessing a variable (function scope) within a loop.

I'm defining *let u* right at the beginning of the function. Within a for loop some childs should be appended to that variable *u*. When I inject *u* into the DOM after the loop has finished, no child elements are shown, but within the loop *u* is manipulated (as the console says).

I guess I cannot manipulate the function scoped *u* inside the loop/if block... but, what I understood from let declaration in ES6 - it should work!? Does anyone have an idea? Thanks!

*Background: this is ES6 code transcompiled with babel to ES5 and afterwards compiled to an Apache Cordova app running on Windows 10/UWP, this may help*

```
export function buildSubNavigation(parent) {

let u = $('<ul>')
    .addClass('subNavbarList');

for (let p in window.pages) {
    if(window.pages[p]['parent'] == parent){

        let i = $('<li>')
            .addClass('subNavbarItem')
            .attr('id','subNavbarItem' + window.pages[p]['id'])
            .click(function(){
                // bind functions
                //...
            });
        // console prints proper list items
        console.log(i);
        // console prints u including list childs
        u.append(i);
    }
}

// inject into page
// no list childs are injected to DOM, only UL element
$('#subNavbar').html(u);
//...
}
```

Comment: *"but, what I understood from let declaration in ES6 - it should work!?"* Yes. `var`, `let`, `const` would all work. JavaScript has lexical scope, that didn't change with ES6.

Comment: Well, thanks. But what's the issue here then?

Comment: Don't know. Works fine in my slightly adapted version: https://jsfiddle.net/aapud0ub/ . Maybe there is an issue with code you didn't post.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out, that the code itself was clean and did not produce the error. It was some error on the ES6 Babel translation of the code that was solved after re-installing the modules via npm.